# PHP output DataURI base64_encode

Tags: php, data-uri

I want to take a local image, resize it and output the dataURI.  Why is my base64_encode code not working?

```
<?php
// Create an image instance

$imagearray = array('pop3', 'aboutme', 'passions', 'lindahlstudios', 'blog');

foreach ($imagearray as $key) {
    echo $key;

    //load image
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($key.'button4.png');

    //set width of resize
    $width = 70;
    $ratio = $width / imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im) * $ratio;

    echo ' resizeTo-'.$width.'x'.$height.'<br>';

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

    //save image to file
    //imagepng($new_image, $key.'button4_'.$width.'.png');

    //print DataURI
    echo base64_encode($new_image);

    imagedestroy($new_image);
}
?>
```

Comment: first & simple: did you prefixed it with "data:"?

Comment: See the answer but no I didn't - it wasn't echoing anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`imagecreatetruecolor` returns an image resource, what you need to create the data uri is an image file, also the data uri format is [`data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format)

```
echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($new_image_file));
```

If you don't want to save a file to read, you can use `imagepng` and output buffering

```
 ob_start();
 imagepng($new_image);
 echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: So basically I cannot do it without saving the file, all I need to do is save image to file and then load it.  Just added/modified the code and it works. Thanks!

Comment: for sure you can!

open an output buffer and clean-get it after you PRINTED the "jpg" or something...

Comment: You can do it without saving file to disk

Comment: @Musa Sweet.  Thanks for that revision.  Also you forgot the comma after base64

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, despite being too... awkward. I never heard of that ob_start() functions.