# Attaching media file from outside web directory php

Tags: php

Is there a way to attach a media file like this in php?

```
$handle = fopen("/var/record/rec1.wav", "wb");
echo "<embed src =\"$handle\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you could encode it as a [data uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127751/php-output-datauri-base64-encode), but that means dealing with [browser support](http://caniuse.com/datauri) issues and having having to reload the entire media file every time the HTML document loads instead of caching them separately.

```
$path = "/var/record/rec1.wav";
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
$uri = 'data:audio/x-wav;base64,'.$data;
?>
<embed src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($uri); ?>" 
       hidden="true" 
       autostart="true">
</embed>
```

You'd be better off just exposing the file over HTTP directly.

Comment: Well the software saves it there and you can't change it.  Would a symlink work inside the www?

Comment: @Sethe23 — That depends on how your HTTP server is configured. You could also have a separate PHP script to read the file and echo it back out on its own URI.

Comment: Am I missing something with that code?  It doesn't play the file when embedded.

Comment: I misremembered the MIME type for WAV files. Fixed.

Comment: Nice! Why does the source `
    <embed src="data:audio/x-wav;base64,UklGRmTCAgBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAQB8AAIA+AAACABAAZGF0YUDCAgAIAAAA8P/w//j/CAD4//D/CAAIAPD/EADw/wgAAAAIAAgACAAIAPD/8P8AABAA+P8IAAAA8P/w//D/+P/4//j/+P/4//j/+P8IAAAA8P8IAAAACAD4//j/EAD4//D/AADw//j/CAD4/wgACAD4/wgACAD4//j/+P8IAPj/8P8IAPD/CAAQAAgAAAD4//j/CAAAAAgAAAAIAPj/+P/4/+j/AAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAQAAgACAAIAPj/+P8AAPj/CAAAABAACADo/wAAGAD4//D/+P/w//j/+P8IAAAAAAD4/wAACADw/wgACAD4//j/CAAIAPj/+P/4/wgAAAAAAPj/AAD4/wAAEAD4//j/AAAQAPj/+P/4//D/CAD4/wgACAAAAPj/=D4//j/+P/4//j/+P8AAAgA+P/w/wgA` look like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58582/discussion-between-sethe23-and-quentin).